# Why does an IBAction's sender type have to be id?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, ibaction, nsbutton

I'm learning Cocoa with "Cocoa Programming For Mac OS X right now (the Objective-C edition)" and whenever I create a button with Interface Builder, I have to connect it with one of the classes I am currently working with.

When I control click-drag from the button to my AppDelegate.h file, Xcode will automatically hook the button to my AppDelegate class. If I choose "Action" it will create a method like this:

```
- (IBAction)onButtonPress:(id)sender {
}
```

Objective-C's methods work like this:

```
- (returnType)methodName:(typeOfFirstArgument)firstArgumentName (typeOfSecondeArgument)secondArgumentName
```

Why do I have to use the type `id` for the sender instead of `NSButton`? I know that I hooked the method up with a button. As a consequence, I expect the sender to be a object of type `NSButton`.

I tried that but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type does not have to be `id`. You can most definitely change the type and name of the parameter, either using the pop-up when you create the connection, or in the code.

`id` is a type meaning "pointer to any ObjC object". A pointer to a specific class works just as well:

```
- (IBAction)onButtonPress:(NSButton *)importantButton;
```

Comment: A key detail here for people new to the language is that `id` is a generic **pointer**, so when you replace it you need to use something like `NSButton *` and **not** `NSButton`.

Comment: Uh! I didn't know that. Could you provide an example why you would use id over the distinct type you are expecting?

Comment: You would use `id` only if you were expecting different objects to call this method and need to pass themselves in, @user148013. Or if you didn't really care about the sender at all.

Comment: I would disagree with some of what is being said here.  `id` should be the default choice for actions, for the simple reason that it establishes a more general and flexible interface.  If you declare sender to be `NSButton*`, you are saying that only `NSButton`s are allowed to call this action.  If you later decide that you want an `NSMenuItem`, say, to call the action too, you will actually have to change your object's interface to allow that.  Bad.  Unless you have a specific reason to require a sender of a specific class, don't do so.  Objective-C is supposed to be more dynamic than that.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: It does NOT have to be an id, if you look at the small dialog that popped up where you select "Action" and name the handler, you will see that you can select the actual type of the object, NSButton in your example.